# How to use "if" $class = ($value->status == "done") ? "#336699" : "";

Tags: php

how to use 'if' here:

```
$class = ($value->status == "open") ? "#336699" : "";
```

This above works good but I wanna to use three colors to mark three statuses like:

```
if ($class = ($value->status == "open")){ ? "#336699" : "";}
elseif($class = ($value->status == "in_progress")){ ? "#436699" : "";}
elseif($class = ($value->status == "done")){ ? "#536699" : "";}
```

But of course it dosent work. Any help for that?

Thanks for an idea. Working fine:

```
$class = ($value->status == "open") ? "#336699" :  $class = ($value->status == "in_progress") ? "#536699" :  $class = ($value->status == "done") ? "#936699" : "";
```

Comment: Store the value in a variable in the `if/else` block and use that variable.

Comment: Also note, that JS has no `elseif`. You need to put a space in between to fake one: `else if`.

Comment: Please add necessary tags to get attention of concerned community

Comment: Use switch(status) http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

Comment: `$value->status` is a syntax error. This is not JavaScript.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's only tagged [javascript] but the code clearly is not javaScript.

Comment: @Oriol In my understanding, OP is using some framework, hence syntax if weird. `($value->status == "in_progress")){ ?`, `$value->status`, `elseif` all are not supported by JS. Hence my previous comment to add necessary tags

Comment: Didn't even see the tag. Just knew it was `PHP`

Comment: @Rajesh Then the question must specify the framework. An answer is not possible if we don't know what technologies the OP is using.

Comment: @Oriol True. I though OP is a new user and should be given sometime provide necessary details. Hence I thought a comment should be enough. Also, if you are downvoting answers because of syntax error, there is a possibility that they know what framework is used and they might be correct.

Comment: The OP has changed the tag to PHP, I think you should revoke the "hold" suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I would do this:

```
const colors = { 
   'open': '#330989', 
   'close': '#330989', 
  'progress': '#330989'
}

const activeClass = colors[$value.status]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want really to use conditional (ternary) Operator, The condition could be :

```
$status = "done";
$class = ($status == "open") ? "#336699" : ($status == "in_progress") ? "#436699" : ($status == "done") ? "#536699" : "";
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `$value->status` is a `SyntaxError`

Answer (score 0):

Like this.using nesting ternary operator.Use `dot` operator for accessing object values in javascript.

```
$value = $status.value;
$class = ($value== "open")? "#336699":($value == "in_progress")?"#436699":"#536699";
```

Comment: `$status->value` is a `SyntaxError`

Comment: @ Oriol need to dot operator for accessing object in javascript.

Comment: THANKS FOR HELP/IDEA. IT'S WORKING:

Comment: what is output on `console.log($value)`.